# which observer to call while removing item from cart and empty cart in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

Is there an observer which can be used to observe events when a product is removed from the cart? I haven't found any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'sales_quote_remove_item' action for observer and implement functionality whatever you want.